# What are delegates, how are they used?

Tags: vb.net, delegates, invoke

After being alerted by a user that the basis of my question was based on erroneous knowledge I have edited the title of this question with what should have been my original question and have erased the previous content. Below is, what I think, an excellent explanation of delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you are saying, your ideas regarding `delegates` do not seem to be completely clear. Thus, the whole point of this answer is clarifying what delegates actually are such that you can apply this knowledge to understand the code you propose or any other delegate-related situation.

Delegates are a way to treat functions as variables. That is, instead of doing `Dim myString as String = "this"`, substituting "this" with a function.

Simple code to clarify what a delegate is and how it has to be treated:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Delegate Sub subDelegate(arg1 As String, arg2 As String)
    Public subDelegateVar As subDelegate

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        subDelegateVar = New subDelegate(AddressOf origSub)
        subDelegateVar.Invoke("this", "that")

    End Sub

    Public Sub origSub(arg1 As String, arg2 As String)
        MsgBox("I want to write " & arg1 & " and " & arg2)
    End Sub

End Class
```

You have the function (`Sub`) `origSub` and you want to treat it as a variable. First thing you have to do is declaring a delegate matching its structure:

```
Public Delegate Sub subDelegate(arg1 As String, arg2 As String)
```

This is like defining a `type` (the `string type` in the example above). Next step is declaring a variable associated with this type (`myString` in the example above), what is done with the following code:

```
Public subDelegateVar As subDelegate
```

And the third step is assigning this variable to the value you want (`myString = "this"`) what is done via:

```
subDelegateVar = New subDelegate(AddressOf origSub)
```

What is `Invoke` here for? Just for calling the given function. Why creating a new variable (delegate), assigning a function to it and using Invoke to call the function instead of calling this function directly? Because some times you need the function to be treated as a variable; for example: when you want to pass it (the whole function) as an argument to another function -> this is one of the reasons why delegates are required, not the only one (not even close).

Comment: Thanks this clarifies things; I will edit the question so that those that are wishing to learn about delegates can find it.

Comment: Relating to threading, I know you can't call a GUI update function from a background thread, yet I can't see how creating a variable (delegate), assigning the GUI update function to it, and then calling it solves this problem. How is this any different than calling the function itself?

Comment: @UrielKatz A function/sub is there and you cannot refer to it in any way other than for calling it (as Invoke does). For example, if I want to create n buttons and associate n functions to their click event at runtime, I would have to rely on delegates. Every time you perform any kind of dynamic action with a function at runtime you have to rely on delegates (well... or on other lambda expressions). You deleted your code and I don't have too much experience with background worker and thus I cannot be more precise in my answer.